# Timeout issue on a paginated query SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have a paginated query which takes < 1s in SSMS but when I try to hit it through the rest end point I get this error,

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

There are total 60000 records it API works fine for the starting pages but if I go to the pages at the end the error is thrown I have increased the timeout but it does not help.

```
SELECT 
    A, B, C
FROM b WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN s WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.Id = b.x
INNER JOIN c WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.c = c.e
INNER JOIN fba WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.v = fba.b
INNER JOIN rfm WITH (NOLOCK) ON fba.a = rfm.n
ORDER BY createdDate DESC 
      OFFSET 67560 rows FETCH NEXT 10 rows ONLY;
```

**EDIT**

I ran the execution plan and joining with 2 tables showed 35% cost each on Clustered index Seek, I am not sure what that means but removing the those 2 tables in the join made it work. I am still looking for the exact root cause.

Comment: Why are you abusing `NOLOCK` in your query? Are aware that it will cause your results to be wrong?

Comment: @Larnu - I am aware, I was just testing this is not related to the issue.

Comment: `which takes < 1s`, Really?

Comment: @A_Sk - Yes in the SSMS it does

Comment: No one can help you without understanding your schema and your goal with this query. It would help everyone - including future generations that will follow behind you - to use best practices and give every table an alias and reference every column using that alias. In addition, examples involving cryptic names do not help anyone understand your issue and frequently discourage people from helping. Perhaps you seek help from your team members or the dba first,